Can I share a Live Motion Photo as a video?
I have a Pixel 7a with the default/built-in camera app, which sometimes makes a short video when I take a photo. (I believe in iOS these are called "Live Photos" and maybe Google call them "Motion Photos"?)
Anyway, one of these little clips that it made is kind of fun and I want to share it. But when I use the share panel it just wants to give me the main still photo instead of the video clip. I found the "Shots in this photo" but again that is just individual stills.
Is there a way to share the video that it shows on a loop, as a video without choosing individual photos?

"Motion Photos are JPEG/HEIC image with a short MP4 video embedded after the image data. The image part of these files can be opened in any image viewer that supports JPEG/HEIC, but the video part cannot." source. This means you need an app that extracts the video data after the image.

Related (but not necessarily duplicate) to Robert's comment: How do I view Google Camera's motion photos on my Windows PC?

I did find a way as I was posting the question :-) Maybe there's easier ways so I leave it for others to find and/or chime in but:
In the same photo details panel where I found the "Shots in this photo" (same screen that shows you other stuff like the geolocation and lens and file size details…) there is an export. For me this screen can be reached via the three dots or by swiping up.
Anyway at the top of this slide-up details panel there's a sideways scrolling area with a bunch of buttons. Mine are "Move to folder" / "Copy to folder" / "Detelete from device" / "Export" / etc. and it's this Export button that works! It has three options, to export as:

Video
GIF
Still photo

and an option whether to "Keep stabilization" you can use with the video and (animated) GIF options. When you export it creates a copy of the live/motion photo but now as an outright video in your camera roll. And of course then you can share that exported video file however you want then, as a video.

Confirmed the Export option does the job on Pixel4 (on both the viewer app that camera app links to, and Google Photo app).
